# Failed to resolve: com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1+

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, fresco

I have a problem adding the `fresco` dependency in my project.
Here some screenshots of problem

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can use the current version  https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Answer (score 3):

You have to change

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1+'
```

with

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1'
```

The version **0.8.1+ doens't exist**.

I suggest you avoiding the use of the `+` but if you want to use it, you can use one of these:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.+'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.+'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:+'
```